Voltage biased Josephson junction
Consider a pure Josephson element (i.e. a Josephson junction, whose capacitive behaviour is neglected).
The hamiltonian of an isolated Josephson element is
$$H_T = -E_J \cos \hat \varphi$$
Now, suppose we apply a classical voltage $V=cost$ accross the junction.
In his notes on circuit QED, Girvin says that this voltage bias had to the hamiltonian the term
$$U = -2eV \hat n$$
$\hat n$ is the charge number operator, that counts counts how many Cooper pairs have passed from one side of the junction to the other, while $\hat \varphi$ is the phase operator, which is the canonically conjugate operator.
Why does the voltage source carry exactly that term in the hamiltonian?
